# Unable to select or print searchbar filtered array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have 3 buttons to pick 3 items from tableview with search.
Every thing works fine until when i search and select a row.

when i select row..it prints "nothing selected" which i included in code of switch statement default.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if isSearching == true{

        tableData = filteredArray

        switch filteredArray {

        case signUser.countries:
            signUser.country = tableData[indexPath.row]
            self.btnCountry.titleLabel?.text = signUser.country
            print(signUser.country)

        case signUser.dawatTitles:
            signUser.dawatName = tableData[indexPath.row]
            self.btnDawat.titleLabel?.text = signUser.dawatName

        case signUser.nationalities:
            signUser.nationality = tableData[indexPath.row]
            self.btnNationality.titleLabel?.text = signUser.nationality

        default:
            print("nothing selected")
        }
    }
    else if isSearching == false{

        tableData = unfilteredArray

        switch unfilteredArray{

        case signUser.countries:
            signUser.country = tableData[indexPath.row]
            print(signUser.country)

        case signUser.dawatTitles:
            signUser.dawatName = tableData[indexPath.row]
            print(signUser.dawatName)

        case signUser.nationalities:
            signUser.nationality = tableData[indexPath.row]
            print(signUser.nationality)

        default:
            print("dsds")
        }
    }
}
```

when i search and select country or any item..it should print the selected country or row.

it works without search

Comment: remove some space from the code. it's pretty difficult to read

Comment: i am sorry..i am new here

Comment: You should use a single array for your table. Update that array according to searching.

Answer (score 1):

You have on your button actions ( I saw this before you edited the question) :

```
        self.unfilteredArray = signUser.dawatTitles
// ...
        self.unfilteredArray = signUser.countries
//...
        self.unfilteredArray = signUser.nationalities
```

and in the switch from the table view did select you basically

```
//...
        switch filteredArray {
        case signUser.countries: 
//...
// is the filteredArray the signUser.countries ?
// well … never because you never assing them
```

Solution:

Keep the selection from your buttons in a varibale

Somehting like :

```
enum Options { 
  case dawatTitles
  case countries
  case nationalities
}


var lastSelection: Options? 

/// ... when a button is pressed 
lastSelection = Options.nationalities //for example


and in the table view did select 


    switch lastSelection {
    case countries: 
 //  is searching ... bla bla
```

Still... there seems to be other stuff that might be improved in your code as well.